# Jersey JAXB question

Tags: jersey

I have a pojo that is returned as a response of one of rest service call. My app is using Jersey's JAXB for serialization.
This pojo just exposes a Long field and all other fields which again are pojos are annotated with @XmlTransient.

Now I need one such pojo that is a class field to be the part of response. I was hoping that just getting rid of @XmlTransient will be enough, however this object is still null when I do this.

Can some one please provide an insight into this issue. I am new to Rest Services and hence to JAX-RS, Jersey etc too. I would appreciate if you can also suggest any good books or online documentation to kick start my learning.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the serialized XML to see if it's the marshalling or unmarshalling that didn't work.

I'm not sure I understand what datatype you are trying to pass: Is it a java class? Brings back memories of Jini :-) It's probably better to pass the class name as a String in the XML. (please read up on reflection.)